# Domain of Attributes for an Entity?

Tags: erd, domain

I am new to DBMS and was reading about the ER Model and entities-attributes. I found the following line in the book which I was reading:

> The domain of Composite attributes is the cross product of domains of
> component attributes.

Which is fairly straight forward and intuitive. However, I was not able to understand the line following it:

> The domain of Multi-valued attributes is a set of subsets of values
> from the basic domain.

I couldn't understand this line. I know [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), which is set of all subsets of a set. Does this line mean, The domain is the power set of the basic domain set? I tried searching on the web before posting, but couldn't find any related literature/ explanation.

A simple language explanation would help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from the book "Database system concepts". Here's what that means:

Suppose `C` is a composite attribute of an entity type, which has 3 attributes : `A1`, `A2`, `A3`. Suppose, only `A3` is multivalued.
Now say the domain of these 3 attributes contain 5, 4, 3 elements respectively.

> The domain of Multi-valued attributes is a set of subsets of values
> from the basic domain.

This means, the multi-valued attribute's (`A3` in our case) domain will be the [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the basic domain set.

So, in our case, the power set of `A3` will contain 2^3 = 8 elements. So, the composite attribute `C` will contain 5x4x8 = 160 elements.

In case A3 was not multi-valued, then the domain of C would contain 5x4x3 = 60 elements.